# Java: threads is not releasing after out of scope

Tags: java, out-of-memory, executorservice, threadpoolexecutor

SOLVED: Sorry, problem had nothing to do with Java Threads. C3P0's ComboPooledDataSource was creating so many threads and not releasing them. After switching to DBCP2's BasicDataSource, the thread count doesn't go up anymore.

I wrote a web app and it crashes due to not able to create anymore threads. In one of the function, I have the `ExecutorService` creating a thread pool of 10 threads as a local variable of that function. When I monitor the threads, every time the function is called, about ~12 threads are getting created.

I then moved it to a test file and run this in multiple shells:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    testRun();

    Thread.sleep(1253234234);
}      

public static testRun() {
   WorkQueue queue = new ThreadPool(10);
     for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        queue.addJob(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                System.out.println(this);
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(5000);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }});
    }
    queue.startJobs();
    queue.wait(10);
}

public void wait(int seconds) {
    executor.shutdown();
    try {
        if (!executor.awaitTermination(seconds, TimeUnit.SECONDS)) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Thread pool terminated unexpectedly due to time out.");
        }
    } catch (InterruptedException ie) {
        throw new RuntimeException("Thread interrupt event is received while waiting for termination of ThreadPool - " + ie.getMessage());
    }
}
```

This creates 25 threads in every shell, then release only 10 after it's done. So every time this function is called, there're 15 threads that are not getting released. I'm going to guess the 15 is the maxPoolSize, and the 10 is the corePoolSize. But why aren't they all getting released when function finished?

So I thought maybe I'm not understanding this `ExecutorService` class and write the raw thread:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    testRun();

    Thread.sleep(1253234234);
}

private static void testRun() throws Exception {

    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        Thread t = new Thread(new Runnable() { 
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(5000);
                    System.out.println(this);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
        t.start();
    }
}
```

These now creates 27 threads for every shell and release 10 after each function finished. What am I doing wrong? How do I release these threads local to a function? Can someone point me to the right way?

Please ignore compile/syntax error as I replaced the test content after testing it, so this isn't copy and paste off of working code.

Thank you.

Comment: Do you instantiate executor service once or each time when call your function?

Comment: Well, if you look at the code, you could see Thread or ThreadPool was initiated each time inside the function as local variable. ExecutorService is just an instance variable of ThreadPool class.

Comment: Never mind. This test was skewed because every main function uses 13 threads by default so even without creating threads, every shell was generating 13 threads. The problem lies somewhere else. I'm going to investigate further.